# Emulate an RFID card with android 4.4?

Tags: nfc, 4.4-kitkat

Is it possible to do it with the host card emulation feature of android 4.4?
Is there a sample how this framework works?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html

Comment: RFID card is very unspecific. What type of RFID card?